# Error with show popunder in tablet or Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my template I include a tool to show a pop-under when it is in tablet devices and other pop-under when it is other devices( cellphone, desktop,etc )
I tested and work perfect with banner, but when I try to use pop-under does not work, and I don';t know how fix it, If somebody can help   me, thanks..

```
 }
        if(is_tablet==1) {
            $("#tablet-ad-space").show();
            $("#mobile-ad-space").remove();
        }
        else {
            $("#tablet-ad-space").remove();
            $("#mobile-ad-space").show();       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hide() function insted of remove() because remove() remove element from DOM.

Comment: thanks fro answering me, have the same result, the pop under still showing in both, tablet and the rest, but when i use banner this work good. but I need that this work for popunder. I reviewed the source and still showing the pop under code, if you have other idea, let me know.. thanks..